# In the new-style Settings interface in Win10, how do I cancel changes? (Use case: power & sleep)

Tags: windows-10, control-panel, windows-10-v1709

Win10 provides Windows 7-style Control Panel views that have a "Cancel" button to dismiss a screen without saving changes.  Is there a similar option in the Windows 10-style settings views?  I can't find it via manual inspection, Google search, or SU search in [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10).

Use case: I just opened the new-style Power & Sleep settings and tried to scroll with the keyboard.  However, I didn't realize that the "On battery power, turn screen off after" dropdown had keyboard focus.  I therefore have changed the timeout but have no idea what it was before!  I would like to cancel but can't figure out how.

I agree this is not a very significant problem :) .  However, I would like to be prepared should I need to cancel a more important change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "cancel" as you note, because the entire concept of the settings has changed subtly. There's also no "OK" button. The settings are "set" upon selection.

Given this new method, the solution is not so much to set things back to what they were as it is to set them to what you want them to be.

NOTE: You can still access most of the "old" configuration utilities if you know their actual name.

The Power Options control panel item is the utility `powercfg.cpl`. Type that into the Start Menu or Run box and you'll get the old-style utility.

However, as these are very likely to go away in future versions of Windows, I suggest it is better to learn the new way and become more comfortable and fluent in it.